# How to setup a one-writer, one-reader system between a python script updating data from my home computer and an RPI reading the data?

Tags: python

This is my first project involving IOT, or even very much internet protocol for that matter.

**THE SHORT:**
I have a few programs on my home computer that search for live stock price data continuously. I have also designed a stock ticker from an RPI that I want to be able to read that data. I have no idea where to begin and I am looking for advice.

**THE LONG:**
After some tests, I feel confident that the Raspberry Pi Zero does not have enough power to hold it's own for every step of this project. I was originally having the "client," the RPI0, fetch stock data from the APIs I currently use, put it into a string, and scroll that string across a 1602 display. This method encountered additional problems as the data couldn't scroll smoothly, since not every data fetch takes the same amount of time.

The goal is therefore that I use my desktop (or a beefier RPI) at my house to fetch the stock data and format it the way I want it to be displayed, so that the RPI0(s) only have to fetch the pre-fetched and formatted string, and scroll through it.

**THE SOLUTION I NEED:** It seems like this should seem fairly straightforward, but despite a fair amount of time spent on my end, I can't find a reasonable solution. Ideally, my computer continuously updates a string and puts it somewhere on the internet where my RPI0 can quickly download it and scroll the text across its display.

What resources are available that can provide something like this?; preferably free and intended for beginners?

Comment: Unless you are really looking up LOTS of data, I would be very surprised if a Raspberry Pi Zero was not able to process querying a few APIs and driving a 1602 display. It's more likely an issue in the way your code is structured than anything...

Comment: feel free to provide us a link to your code github for review. Be sure to take out any private info such as API keys, etc 
Maybe you'll find that the zero is your hero, after all !

Answer (score 1):

At the moment, perhaps you're not wanting to have your code reviewed as I suggested in the comment. So, if you actually want to go ahead and try to do the solution you proposed, here are some options for storing that string:

1. You can simply store an S3 object and access it from the zero. If there isnt any personal info, you can even just even expose that S3 bucket for read on the internet so that you dont have any authentication issues from the zero. You may want to turn object versioning off. This is probably your easiest option.
2. You can store it in a google spreadsheet and access it via API. As long as you dont hammer it with requests, you should be ok.
3. Look at airtable
4. Its also possible to use IoT platforms such as AWS IoT, Azure IoT and even google pub/sub. This is different from what you asked for, but it is an option.